# How to update user's profile in express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to update a particular user's financial records which is an array.

<-- This is my user model -->

```
const FinanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  moneyToBePaid: {
    type: Number,
  },

  moneyPaid: {
    type: Number,
  },

  moneyToBeReceived: {
    type: Number,
  },

  moneyReceived: {
    type: Number,
  },
});
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  financialInformation: [FinanceSchema],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

<-- This is my post route -->

```
router.post("/users/:id/profile", async (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id;
  const {
    moneyToBePaid,
    moneyPaid,
    moneyToBeReceived,
    moneyReceived,
  } = req.body;
  const finance = {
    moneyToBePaid,
    moneyPaid,
    moneyToBeReceived,
    moneyReceived,
  };
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(_id);
    user.financialInformation.push(finance);
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  }
```

<-- This is my update route -->

```
router.patch("/users/:user_id/profile/:profile_id", async (req, res) => {
  const user_id=req.params.user_id;
  const profile_id=req.params.profile_id;
  try {
    
    
  }
```

I am confused how to update a particular user's particular finance record.

Comment: what is profile_id?

Comment: FinancialInformation _id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to update the moneyPaid property of specific finance array element:

```
try {
    const user_id=req.params.user_id;
    const profile_id=req.params.profile_id;
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id": user_id, "financialInformation._id": profile_id },
        { 
            "$set": {
                "financialInformation.$.moneyPaid": "2258" // the data you want to update
            }
        });

    res.status(200).send('user updated');
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It is working now.I am new to Backend..There is just one issue.Right now I am hardcoding moneyPaid to 300.Is there a way to dynamically update financialInfo.$.moneyPaid?

Comment: Yes, you can use any value inside `req.body` to update the value you want.